# One router and one modem+router. Can I pass a static IP range from one to the other?

Tags: networking, routing, router, modem, pppoe

I had been running a Huawei HG612 connected to a DD-WRT router for internet services using PPPoE as authentication.

Due to an office move, I need to have a DG834 modem+router which will be used for connecting to a **PPPoA** network. After that, the router running DD-WRT will take over for the NATing and firewall rules.

There is 1 dynamic IP and 5 static IPs available to us. Is there a configuration I can implement where the modem takes the dynamic IP and the DD-WRT router is passed traffic for the 5 static IPs? I've been looking at static routes but I'm a bit out of my depth!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the manal for the dg834gt, you should be able to do this as follows -

1. Set up the router "as normal" so that the ADSL (PPPoA) connection works.
2. Set the LAN range as 192.168.0.x - make sure both your DG834 and DD-WRT router are
   in the same range AND HAVE STATIC IP ADDRESSES ASSIGNED.
3. Set up a static route with your subnet with the gateway being the 192.18.x.x address of
   the DD-WRT router.  You can do this in advanced -> Static Routes.  (See page 102 of [this](http://downloadcenter.netgear.com/en/Disclaimer.aspx?redirecturl=http://netgeardownload.registria.com/single_page_registration?product%5Bsku%5D=dg834gt&download_url=http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/DG834GT/DG834GT_V1.03.23.zip)
   manual).

Depending on your model (according to [this](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php/139095-Netgear-dg834gt-Half-bridge-mode) link), you might also be able to use "Half Bridge" mode, which pushes the external IP address to the DD-WRT using DHCP.   (Although I don't have the luxury of a subnet routed to my ADSL connection, I also have a PPPoA connection and use a cheap dynalink modem to do half bridging to my Linux box - this is probably a better solution) as it makes your ADSL router seemless to the wider Internet and is probably simpler to configure.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works inbound, but doesn't appear to work outbound as I now have 2 NATs operating on the network. Is there a way I can safely disable the NAT on the DG834?

Comment: Have a look at http://support.zen.co.uk/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle.aspx?articleid=10048 - Specifically there appears to be a setting to disable NAT.  As you have valid IP's you should be able to disable this OK.  REMEMBER THAT IF YOU DONT HAVE NAT YOU NEED TO SET UP FIREWALLING - POSSIBLY ON EACH DEVICE, OR THEY WILL BE DIRECTLY ACCESSIBLE AND MORE VULNERABLE TO HACKING.